# Where is the best location to save in Android mobile using AIR and how

Tags: android, actionscript-3, mobile, air, saving-data

Where is the best location to save in Android mobile using AIR and how? Im trying to figure out where i can save my file. Im creating a MEMO App where the user can save his/her File, my question is, where is the best location in Android Mobile so save?

Comment: You should look for the analog of Shared Preferences or databases handling in AIR

Comment: I already gave an answer but I think it's not clear what you are actually trying to do. Are you trying to save data that is used internally by your app, or a file that the user would expect to use external to your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is what `File.applicationStorageDirectory` is for.

You can save whatever data you want to the file (XML, JSON, AMF, sqlite database), and you can save asynchronously to avoid UI hangs.

Example saving string data (such as serialized XML or JSON):

```
function save(data:String):void {
    var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("preferences.data");
    var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE); // or openAsync()
    fileStream.writeUTFBytes(data);
    fileStream.close();
}

function load():String {
    var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("preferences.data");
    var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    fileStream.open(file, FileMode.READ);
    var data:String = fileStream.readUTFBytes(fileStream.bytesAvailable);
    fileStream.close();
    return data;
}
```

Comment: got 2 questions Aaron. 
  1. How to create a folder and put the saved file in it.
  2. When trying to load my file, my android device says 'No files were found'( i used browseForOpen)

Comment: 1. You can use `File/createDirectory()`, but I'm not sure what you're trying to do, 2. are there any files in the directory you're browsing? `applicationStorageDirectory` is specific to your app, it's not a directory that the user would normally have any files. You could try something like `File.documentsDirectory`. [More info on Android file locations.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fe4.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7d9e)

Comment: Where is the asynchronous part?    @Darvlaskie - I'm not sure what else you expect to get here that wasn't in your first question...

Comment: My example doesn't use `openAsync()`, but using that function on the `File` is the only difference for writing, and for reading you wait for `Event.COMPLETE` on the `FileStream` before reading the data.

Comment: The PO doesn't know how to code and needs free code sample doing exactly what he wants so do not assume he will be able to modify your code, he won't. Personally I always ignore those questions as it's the recommended approach here. His next question will be "how to load a saved file on android"

Comment: Hey BotMaster.  first of all, i already solved my problem. Second of all, Why are you here if you dont want to help those people who are less experienced than you? Whats the point of loggin in if you dont intend to help people like me? Lastly, LDMS and Aaron chose to help me and im thankful for that. Im not forcing you to help me. IF you think my questions are too stupid for you, then ignore it. Its just that simple

Comment: @Darvlaskie - It wouldn't kill you though to upvote useful answers like this one and accept answers that led to your solution.  It actually helps your StackOverflow profile.